# How to express this mathematical equality in python

Tags: python, modular-arithmetic

How do I do this calculation in python? 
[image]

This is what I tried but I guess it's wrong:

```
 v=(pow(g,s,p)*pow(modinv(b, p), h, p))%p
```

Comment: `v = (pow(g, s) * pow(b, -h)) % p`

Comment: @CoryKramer: would you post your answer as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: Unless you know that `v < p`, you need to `%p` _both_ sides.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler than that. Try like this:

```
v = (pow(g,s) * pow(b,-h)) % p
```

Comment: That's an assignment, not an equality. Also, "simpler", but also less efficient. Those additional functions OP is using are for making `pow` much faster for large numbers if you want to take the modulus anyways.